# Number of items in the aggregation with MongoDB 2.6

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My query looks like that:

```
var x = db.collection.aggregate(...);
```

I want to know the number of items in the result set. The documentation says that this function returns a cursor. However it contains far less methods/fields than when using `db.collection.find()`.

```
for (var k in x) print(k);
```

Produces

```
_firstBatch
_cursor
hasNext
next
objsLeftInBatch
help
toArray
forEach
map
itcount
shellPrint
pretty
```

No `count()` method! Why is this cursor different from the one returned by `find()`? `itcount()` returns some type of count, but the documentation says "for testing only".

Using a `group` stage in my aggregation (`{$group:{_id:null,cnt:{$sum:1}}}`), I can get the count, like that:

```
var cnt = x.hasNext() ? x.next().cnt : 0;
```

Is there a more straight forward way to get this count? As in `db.collection.find(...).count()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barno's answer is correct to point out that `itcount()` is a perfectly good method for counting the number of results of the aggregation. I just wanted to make a few more points and clear up some other points of confusion:

> No `count()` method! Why is this cursor different from the one returned by `find()`?

The trick with the `count()` method is that it counts the number of results of `find()` on the server side. `itcount()`, as you can see in the code, iterates over the cursor, retrieving the results from the server, and counts them. The "it" is for "iterate". There's currently (as of MongoDB 2.6), no way to just get the count of results from an aggregation pipeline without returning the cursor of results.

> Using a group stage in my aggregation `({$group:{_id:null,cnt:{$sum:1}}})`, I can get the count

Yes. This is a reasonable way to get the count of results and should be more performant than `itcount()` since it does the work on the server and does not need to send the results to the client. If the point of the aggregation within your application is just to produce the number of results, I would suggest using the `$group` stage to get the count. In the shell and for testing purposes, `itcount()` works fine.

Comment: So to answer my OP, there's no more straight forward way to get this count (itcount not being an alternative because of the perf)?

Comment: Well, yes, but I dispute that it's not straightforward enough to be called straightforward :D

Answer (score 2):

Where have you read that `itcount()` is "for testing only"?

If in the mongo shell I do
`var p = db.collection.aggregate(...);`

```
printjson(p.help)
```

I receive

```
function () {
    // This is the same as the "Cursor Methods" section of DBQuery.help().
    print("\nCursor methods");
    print("\t.toArray() - iterates through docs and returns an array of the results")
    print("\t.forEach( func )")
    print("\t.map( func )")
    print("\t.hasNext()")
    print("\t.next()")
    print("\t.objsLeftInBatch() - returns count of docs left in current batch (when exhausted, a new getMore will be issued)")
    print("\t.itcount() - iterates through documents and counts them")
    print("\t.pretty() - pretty print each document, possibly over multiple lines")
}
```

If I do

```
printjson(p)
```

I find that

```
"itcount" : function (){
    var num = 0;
    while ( this.hasNext() ){
        num++;
        this.next();
    }
    return num;
}
```

This function

```
 while ( this.hasNext() ){
            num++;
            this.next();
        }
```

It is very similar `var cnt = x.hasNext() ? x.next().cnt : 0;` And this `while` is perfect for count...

Comment: I found it in the Java API actually. It's not even documented on http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/

Comment: Isn't this while loop going to actually fetch all the documents? I believe that the additional aggregate phase is more performant.